# Overlapping div and text on center

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style=" height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:red;">
       <a class="well-link" href="">Test</a>
    <div id="triangle-topleft" style="width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid gray; 
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;">     
    </div>
  
  </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create div like the image i have uploaded using CSS /HTML and Jquery
Please help me
I have tried this.. but not able to get text on center

[image]

Comment: Atleast try some thing then come with what you tried. Please don't just ask on SO without trying anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply achieve that by using `:after` pseudo-element and CSS `transform` property like this:

```css
.div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    z-index: -2;
}
.div:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: green;
    top: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid #000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <a>1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rect with linear gradient

using a single liner gradient you can create this shape.

```css
.rect {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, firebrick 47%, black 47.5%, black 53%, green 53.5%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.rect a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
  <a>1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,But if i want to change color using angularJs ng-style then what i need to pass in background-image ??

Comment: I do not know angularJs but if you want to change the color just change the: linear-gradient(-45deg, firebrick 46%, black 46.2, black 50%, green 50.5%);
Just change the colors of firebrick and green to rgba() or any other colors you would like. Example: linear-gradient(-45deg, pink 46%, black 46.2%, black 50%, blue 50.5%); create a pink and blue shape.